# PowerShell module Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I created a PowerShell module with function `userToBla`:

```
function userToBla
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                   Position = 0)]
        $User
    )

    Begin
    {
        $username = "test\test"
        $password = "XXXXXXXXX"
        $secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
        $password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
        $serverCredential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr
    }

    Process
    {
        Invoke-Command -Credential $serverCredential -ComputerName server1 -ArgumentList $user, $targetAddress -ScriptBlock {
            param ($email,
                   $temail)

            Import-Module ActiveDirectory

            Get-ADUser -filter {(mail -eq $email)} | Set-ADUser -Replace @{postalCode = ($temail)}
            $status = $movestatus.status
        }

        End
        {
        }
    }
```

When I import the module and run `userToBla -user test` the `invoke-command` will not execute on server1 (it looks like its trying to execute the scriptblock on the local system):

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'ActiveDirectory' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

Get-ADUser : The term 'Get-ADUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

-Credential : The term '-Credential' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

If I run the `invoke-command` from the PowerShell console it works without any problems.

Comment: The `Invoke-Command` call isn't the one that's failing.  The `Import-Module` is.

Comment: I agree do you have the Active Directory module installed on the server you are trying to Invoke? also where is your `$serverCredential` set?

Comment: thanks for the comments. ActiveDirectory module is installed on the server (running only the invoke-command works). I forgot to add $serverCredential code

Comment: Usually this happens because the powershell being invoked is not 64bit. Most of the server modules are not available in a 32bit shell.